# Android Studio Socket Server get ipv4 address programatically

Tags: android, sockets, ip

I'm trying to build a chat app. When i try to get wifi ipv4 address from PC, it returns `192.168.1.34` but when i call the same function on Android Studio it returns `192.168.1.232`. Why there is a difference and is there any way to get wifi ipv4 address from Android Studio ? (They are connected to same wifi)

```
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement();
            // drop inactive
            if (!networkInterface.isUp())
                continue;
            // smth we can explore
            Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
                if(addr instanceof Inet6Address) continue;
                if(addr.getHostAddress().startsWith("192.168.1")) {
                    ipv4 =addr.getHostAddress();

                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Why there is a difference" -- because they are two different computers with two different network interfaces. IOW, it is perfectly normal for two computers on the same network to have two different IP addresses.

Comment: That does not change my comment. Two computers on the same WiFi network will have two different IP addresses for that network. That is how TCP/IP networks operate.

Comment: But they are on the same wifi and I'm trying to get wifi ipv4 address.

Comment: So the connection on the client side must be done by manuel ?